# Playing with Box shadows and making Door image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a door portal site and I am trying to make shadow appears left and right and bottom. Just like the walls and shadows on the ground. When I add the bottom (.shadow-longer) the shadows from left and right became dimmer.

```css
div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow:
    -60px 0px 100px -90px #000000,
    60px 0px 100px -90px #000000;
}

/* From Shadow.css */

.shadow-longer {
  box-shadow:
    0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09),
    0 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09),
    0 8px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09),
    0 16px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09),
    0 32px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Don't include links to jsfiddle! You were told not to include it when you posted the question. Create a [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: I want to show my work and to make it easier for collaboration. I saw in the help site: If you are using HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, you can use Stack Snippets to include runnable snippet instead of just a static code block.

Comment: You can create a working snippet from the editor, click on the `<>` button. You can also just include the code in the question and then a link to jsfiddle would be acceptable

Comment: Remember that SO aims to build up a body of questions and answers useful for future readers. It isn’t here just to answer an individuals question. If your code is on an external site it may well either disappear or get corrected, rendering the question useless for others,

Comment: That's because `.shadow-longer`'s `box-shadow` property is overriding the original one. Simply add all of them in one go.